# Community Bot Deletions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There has been a whole slew of answers being deleted by Community Bot recently. I can't see anything obviously wrong with them. Is the bot misbehaving, or is something else going on?

Examples:
[Understanding Freud](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101296/understanding-freud)
[What is an explanation really?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101448/what-is-an-explanation-really)
[Is It Ethical to Disturb a Happy Illusion for the Sake of Reality?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101411/is-it-ethical-to-disturb-a-happy-illusion-for-the-sake-of-reality)
[Is human nature a problem for Marxists?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101457/is-human-nature-a-problem-for-marxists)
[What is the definition of ability?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101408/what-is-the-definition-of-ability)
[What are some points to refute the Mathematical universe hypothesis?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101450/what-are-some-points-to-refute-the-mathematical-universe-hypothesis)
[Am I misinterpreting formulas from which to derive a conclusion in FOL?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101463/am-i-misinterpreting-formulas-from-which-to-derive-a-conclusion-in-fol)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here saying that this was due to a user being destroyed.

Looking at the answers, it looks a lot like AI generated content, all posted in short order. This fits with a user who recently spammed the network with these answers and was suspended network-wide. It may well be we are talking about one of their countless sockpuppet accounts. Seems like some alarms went off and someone pushed the red button.

That would lead to an automated deletion of all the user's content by the bot, as happened here.

If that assumption is correct, knowing my fellow site moderators, I further suspect that it was done by SE staff and not us. The recent cases are because I stopped caring and am nuking any confirmed sockpuppet of said user as soon as I find time.

Speculative, certainly, but fitting the pattern.